# SQL- Join Same Table with Filters

Tags: sql, join, right-join

I have a single table (Tracker) containing 2 columns; (ID and Status). I would like to retrieve a list of ID's without the status approved, however a status can go from pending to approve and the original data will not be removed. See below example and desired outcome.

Tracker Table:

| ID | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Pending |
| 123 | Approved |
| 456 | Pending |
| 678 | Denied |
| 894 | Approved |

Desired Outcome:

| ID | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 456 | Pending |
| 678 | Denied |

`123` is not present due to the second status being 'Approved' and 894 is not present because the only status in 'Approved'

Was thinking along the line of something like below:

```
Select ID
FROM Tracker b
WHERE Status = 'Approved'

Right Join

Select ID
FROM Tracker a

USING ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT T.ID,T.STATUS
FROM YOUR_TABLE AS T
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM YOUR_TABLE AS T2 WHERE T.ID=T2.ID AND T2.STATUS='APPROVED'
 )
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select t.id
from tracker t
group by t.id
having sum(case when t.status = 'Approved' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL.

```
SELECT t.id
       ,t.status
FROM tracker t
GROUP BY id
HAVING sum(
    CASE t.status
        WHEN 'Approved' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
) = 0
;
```